# How to interpret a binary Bitmap picture, so I know which color on which pixel i change when changing something in the Code?

Tags: image, bitmap, binary

I just used this code to convert a picture to binary:

```
import io
tme = input("Name: ")
with io.open(tme, "rb") as se:
  print(se.read())
  se.close()
```

Now it looks like this:

`5MEMMMMMMMMMMMMM777777777777777777777777777777777\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95\x95MEEMMMMEEMM\x96\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97\x97`

And now I want to be able to interpret what this binary code is telling me exactly... I know it ruffly but not enough to be able to do anything on purpose. I searched the web but I didn't find anything that could help me on that point. Can you tell me how is it working or send me a link where I can read how it's done?

Comment: What file format is the image?

Comment: its BMP - Bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just change random bytes in an image. There's a header at the start with the height and width, probably the date and a palette and information about the number of channels and bits per pixel. Then there is the image data which is often padded, and/or compressed.

So you need an imaging library like PIL/Pillow and code something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.bmp').convert('RGB')
px = im.load()

# Look at pixel[4,4]
print (px[4,4])

# Make it red
px[4,4] = (255,0,0)

# Save to disk
im.save('result.bmp')
```

Documentation and examples available [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/index.html).

Comment: I don't use Windows, but it's probably `pip install pillow` or `pip3 install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

The output should be printed in hexadecimal format. The first bytes in bitmap file are `'B'` and `'M'`.

You are attempting to print the content in ASCII. Moreover, it doesn't show the first bytes because the content has scrolled further down. Add `print("start\n")` to make sure you see the start of the output.

```
import io
import binascii
tme = 'path.bmp'
print("start") # make sure this line appears in console output
with io.open(tme, "rb") as se:
  content = se.read()

print(binascii.hexlify(content))
```

Now you should see something like

> ```
> start
> b'424d26040100000000003...
> ```

`42` is hex value for `B`
`4d` is hex value for `M` ...
The first 14 bytes in the file are `BITMAPFILEHEADER`
The next 40 bytes are `BITMAPINFOHEADER`

The bytes after that are color table (if any) and finally the actual pixels.

See [`BITMAPFILEHEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmapfileheader) and [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitmapinfoheader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)